# Javascript not calling servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, web.xml

I am passing a URL from my javascript to call a particular servlet. The configuration is done in web.xml.

Here is my JS call:

```
function ModelForYear()
{   var url = "modelforyear.html";
    var e = document.getElementById("yearId");
    var year = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    url = url + "?yearId=" + year ;    
}
```

Here is my **web.xml** config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ModelByYear</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.harley_davidson.pod.action.ModelByYear</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ModelByYear</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, my servlet class is not called.
Please help.

Comment: Where in your JS code are you sending the HTTP request ? Your function `ModelForYear()` is just constructing an URL string, but how do you actually request for that Servlet from JS ?

Comment: In your JS code you are just creating url variable, but you are not submitting it. You can try with `window.location = url`, as here url is your url variable.

Comment: OR the other alternative is `document.location.href = url`, here the url is the same, your url variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your `ModelForYear()` JS function code.
Write below line as well.

```
 window.location = url;
```

OR an other alternative is,

```
 document.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the OP isn't looking for an AJAX call ?

Comment: AJAX is also may be an alternative, but I just suggested the ways which are possible to call URL from JS.

Answer (score 0):

After you build a URL in the method `ModelForYear()`, you do not do anything with it, so I suggest setting the URL of the browser with the one you created.

You can do so by:

`location.replace(url)`;

After you build the new url